# How does a WPF window know how to access a nested element?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have the following working XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="DrawShape.Window1"
    ...
    <Grid>
        <Polygon Name="poly"/>
    </Grid>           
</Window>
```

In the corresponding C# code, a static callback method (for a property called `Sides`) accesses the `poly` element as follows:

```
static void OnSidesChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    Window1 win = obj as Window1;

    win.poly.Points.Clear();
    ...
```

How is it that `poly` is accessed **directly** through `Window1 win`?  `poly` is nested within a `Grid` element (albeit nameless).  Is this type of access a feature of WPF?

PS: I am aware about the need for access through an object (because the method is static), it is the nesting that I don't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing the WPF logical tree with how names are handled in XAML. In the logical tree the `Polygon` is contained in the `Grid`. However, all names belong to the same scope and are available as fields in the class generated from the XAML.

However, WPF has the concept of [Namescopes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which makes it possible to use the same name in multiple scopes.

> Styles and templates in WPF provide the ability to reuse and reapply content in a straightforward way. However, styles and templates might also include elements with XAML names defined at the template level. That same template might be used multiple times in a page. For this reason, styles and templates both define their own XAML namescopes, independent of whatever location in an object tree where the style or template is applied.

In the simple XAML below you have a `Grid` named `grid` containing a `ListBox` named `listBox`. In the class generated from the XAML there are fields named `grid` and `listBox` allowing the code behind to access both controls.

Each list box item generated by the `ItemTemplate` contains a `TextBlock` named `textBlock`. However, each list box item is in a separate Namescope and there is no field named `textBlock` in the class generated from the XAML.

```
<Grid x:Name="grid">
  <ListBox x:Name="listBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

In this simple example there is no need to name the `TextBlock` objects. However, in more advanced scenarios you may want to refer to named elements within the template, e.g. in triggers.

Comment: You are right, the `Window1` namespace seems to be a flat one.  I added a second nameless `Grid` at the same level w/ the first `Grid`, then tried to add a `Polygon` with name `poly`, and got the error `Name 'poly' already exists in the current name scope.`  Will check the link to better understand scopes.  All this time, I was under the impression there was some hierarchy!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the file `Window1.g.cs` in your project directory.

`Window1.g.cs` contains a partial class that was generated from your XAML. In there you find the variable definition for `poly`.

Comment: the OP trying to  understand what's going under the hood

Comment: Did check that file per your suggestion, and this is how `poly` is declared: `internal System.Windows.Shapes.Polygon poly;` - there is no declaration of the enclosing `Grid`.